Two definitions of order of convergence
Let ${x_n}$ be a sequence which converges to $x$. According to Richard L. Burden, the order of convergence is defined as follows:
A positive real number $\alpha$ is said to be order of convergence of ${x_n}$ if there exists a positive $\lambda$ such that
$$lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|x_{n+1}-x|}{|x_n-x|^{\alpha
}}=\lambda$$
In some other books, order of convergence is defined as follows:
Largest positive real number $\alpha$ is said to be order of convergence of ${x_n}$ if there exists a positive $k$ such that for sufficiently large n
$$|x_{n+1}-x| \leq k|x_n-x|^{\alpha}.$$
I can prove that the first definition implies second one, but for the reverse part, I could only prove that $\{\frac{|x_{n+1}-x|}{|x_n-x|^{\alpha}}\}$ has subsequence which is bounded above by $k$
I want to know that if these two definitions are equivalent or not?
If, yes. How to prove that second definition implies the first one?

It does not, the second statement does not imply the first; and both definitions are not applicable to the bisection method.

Indeed, the second statement does not imply the first, for which the main reason is that the limit may not exist: take for example $x=0$, $\alpha=1$ and $x_n=2^{-n-\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor}$, then $\frac{|x_{n+1}-x|}{|x_n-x|}$ alternates between $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{4}$.
